# How can I do vertical align in a cell with multiple data

Tags: html, css

I want to add to my cell two links and place them on a bottom of my cell.
I've tried "vertical-align:bottom" but it doesn't work in my case:

```
// Append database data here
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Home/JsonWeekEvents",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (i, val) {
            var trow = $('<tr/>').data("id", val.Id);
            //trow.append('<td>' + val.Id + "&nbsp;" + '</td>');
            trow.append('<td style="padding:5px; width:100px; height:70px"></td>');

            trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsW" class="tags" />' +
                '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                '<div style="text-align:center" id="wedVal" class="desc_NumW">' + val.Wednesday + '</div >' +
                '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
                '<div style="vertical-align:bottom;">' +
                '<a  href="#" style="float:left;text-align:left;">Details<a/>' + '<a href="#" style="float:right;text-align:right;">Clear<a />' +
                '</div >' +
                '</div >' +
                '</td>');
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try set follow styles for your div instead vertical-align

```
display:flex; align-items: flex-end;
```

Comment: '<div style="display:flex; center; align-items: bottom;">' +
                    '<a  href="#" style="float:left;text-align:left;">Details<a/>' + '<a href="#" style="float:right;text-align:right;">Clear<a />' +
                    '</div >' , not working :(

Comment: I made a typo and edit my comment. Please check it.

Also you have problem with close tag <a />... it need write as </a>

Comment: Your solution works, but in my case I just needed to throw my div with links out of div with class="ui-widget" and then everythink was ok...but Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go with position:absolute; bottom:0; that would push it to the bottom.